# android amazon s3 upload

Tags: android, amazon-s3

anybody have amazon s3 img upload sample code from android application?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the [AWS SDK for Android](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/)?

Everything you need should be in the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/). Specifically [`PutObjectRequest`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html)

Comment: Thank you Geoff, I will check the documentation.